# Assuming perfect liquidity

Tags: financial-markets, market-model

I encountered this phrase in the textbook by Hans Schumacher

> For the purposes of this textbook, a mathematical model for a financial market consists of a specification of the joint evolution of prices of a number of given assets. Further information that may be important in practice, such as trading restrictions,
> are abstracted away by the assumption of perfect liquidity.

Could anyone explain how assuming perfect liquidity would resolve issues like trading restrictions?

Comment: Textbook available here: https://research.tilburguniversity.edu/en/publications/introduction-to-financial-derivatives

Comment: @Frido Could you make that answer? I don't think your comment can be improved much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A trading restriction could mean that you cannot short certain instruments, or that you cannot execute above/below certain volumes. For example in practice you cannot trade fractional numbers of a stock, let alone irrational numbers. Perfect liquidity basically means none of these restrictions exist, it is an idealization to facilitate modelling.